# How do I inject/integrate a third party library in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, angular6

Some libraries are not supported by Angular like Clappr , HashWords etc . I want to use them in Angular as if they were an Angular library . So  how can we make Angular support external libraries/modules ?

Comment: install the library you want to use then use it as described in documentation

Comment: You might not get every library tuned to work with Angular. You just have to tune it yourself. You can get access to a "node" in Angular that you can hook up libraries that need DOM. Try this: https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02

Comment: @Exterminator , can u share the documentation link for the same ? I couldn't find documentation to make Angular compatible with external unsupported libraries or modules .

Comment: By any chance , do we need to make use   of custom InjectionToken  and use dependency injection to support external libraries and modules . Am i on the right track ?

Comment: you need to google them like this: 'package_name in angular' then it gives you link to the package you can read the documentation from there then download it and use it.

Comment: If the library does not have a typescript module, follow this:
https://hackernoon.com/angular-providers-how-to-inject-3rd-party-library-af4a78722864
If the library does NOT have a TS module, follow this: https://alligator.io/angular/third-party-libraries-angular/

Answer (score 2):

Add the library file in index.html. The variable exposed by the library can be used in component by declaring like this `declare var Clappr: any;` outside the component class.

Answer (score 2):

If the library has a ES6 module, you can just import it.

If the library is just a JS file, you can add the file as if you where importing it using a `<script>` tag on index.html by adding the js file path on the scripts array in angular.json

If types are available you can add them to the types array on typescript.json

Here is a guide to do all that.

https://nitayneeman.com/posts/how-to-add-third-party-library-in-angular-cli/

If you dislike having the third party libraries as global variables you can turn them into inyectables. it's a more involved process but it's pretty neat.

Here is a guide for that too:

https://hackernoon.com/angular-providers-how-to-inject-3rd-party-library-af4a78722864

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I installed in my Angular 9 project:

1. `npm install clappr`
2. Add clappr into `angular.json`:

```
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "scripts": [
            "node_modules/clappr/dist/clappr.min.js"
          ],
          "styles": [
            "./src/styles.css"
          ]
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "scripts": [
            "node_modules/clappr/dist/clappr.min.js"
          ],
          "styles": [
            "./src/styles.css"
          ]
        }
      }
```

3. Create file `index.d.ts` and declare clappr as:

```
declare module 'clappr';
```

4. import it into component.ts file:

```
import * as Clappr from 'clappr';
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the package into your project : `npm i clappr`
2. Import type declaration into Angular app : `app.component.ts`

Answer (score 0):

For Clappr-
In Angular CLI, run the command-

> > npm i clappr

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clappr

Then follow the steps given..

Comment: I tried this but just simply installing it and writing the snippet is not working . Clappr is not compatible with Angular .